# Download images from a URL, save them to App Internal Storage without blocking calls (multiple files in parallel). Using Kotlin Coroutines on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines, android-bitmap

Basically, I am trying to download three different images(bitmaps) from a URL and save them to Apps Internal storage, and then use the URI's from the saved file to save a new Entity to my database. I am having a lot of issues with running this in parallel and getting it to work properly. As ideally all three images would be downloaded, saved and URI's returned simultaneously. Most of my issues come from blocking calls that I cannot seem to avoid.

Here's all of the relevant code

```
    private val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient()

    suspend fun saveImageToDB(networkImageModel: CBImageNetworkModel): Result<Long> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                //Upload all three images to local storage
                val edgesUri = this.async {
                    val req = Request.Builder().url(networkImageModel.edgesImageUrl).build()
                    val response = okHttpClient.newCall(req).execute() // BLOCKING
                    val btEdges =    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response.body?.byteStream())
                    return@async saveBitmapToAppStorage(btEdges, ImageType.EDGES)
                }
                val finalUri = this.async {
                    val urlFinal = URL(networkImageModel.finalImageUrl) // BLOCKING
                    val btFinal = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(urlFinal.openStream())
                    return@async saveBitmapToAppStorage(btFinal, ImageType.FINAL)

                }
                val labelUri = this.async {
                    val urlLabels = URL(networkImageModel.labelsImageUrl)
                    val btLabel = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(urlLabels.openStream())
                    return@async saveBitmapToAppStorage(btLabel, ImageType.LABELS)
                }

                awaitAll(edgesUri, finalUri, labelUri)

                if(edgesUri.getCompleted() == null || finalUri.getCompleted() == null || labelUri.getCompleted() == null) {
                    return@withContext Result.failure(Exception("An image couldn't be saved"))
                }

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Result.failure<Long>(e)
            }

            try {
                // Result.success( db.imageDao().insertImage(image))
                Result.success(123) // A placeholder untill I actually get the URI's to create my Db Entity
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Timber.e(e)
                Result.failure(e)
            }
        }
    }


     //Save the bitmap and return Uri or null if failed
    private fun saveBitmapToAppStorage(bitmap: Bitmap, imageType: ImageType): Uri? {
        val type = when (imageType) {
            ImageType.EDGES -> "edges"
            ImageType.LABELS -> "labels"
            ImageType.FINAL -> "final"
        }

        val filename = "img_" + System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + "_" + type

        val file = File(context.filesDir, filename)

        try {
            val fos = file.outputStream()
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.e(e)
            return null
        }

        return file.toUri()
    }
```

Here I am calling this function

```
    viewModelScope.launch {
            val imageID = appRepository.saveImageToDB(imageNetworkModel)
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                val uri = Uri.parse("$PAINT_DEEPLINK/$imageID")
                navManager.navigate(uri)
            }
        }
```

Another issue I am facing is returning the URI in the first place and handling errors. As if one of these parts fails, I'd like to cancel the whole thing and return `Result.failure()`, but I am unsure on how to achieve that. As returning `null` just seems meh, I'd much prefer to have an error message or something along those lines.

Comment: `I am trying to download three different images(bitmaps) from a URL` Bitmaps? I think you would rather download jpg or png files.

Comment: `//Upload all three images to local storage` ? Download?

Comment: `val btEdges =    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response.body?.byteStream())
                    return@async saveBitmapToAppStorage(btEdges, ImageType.EDGES)
` Why are you creating a bitmap first? Better: save response.body?.byteStream() to file directly. You will keep the same file then. Now they will have different file size for example.

Comment: `val response = okHttpClient.newCall(req).execute() // BLOCKING` Yes. Then why are you using a blocking call? Isn't there an asynchronous one?

Comment: @blackapps I'll save the file directly that's a great point. There isn't one, there's one for callbacks. Preferably I'd like something that suspends

Comment: Then use the callbacks and not coroutines.

Comment: @blackapps by upload to storage I meant that I'd save them to local storage after downloading them. 
As for the first comment, I have no idea, I just want to save the image and be able to load it with it's URI.

Comment: But callbacks are awful and chaining them is awful as well, especially for my usecase